# Is every differentiable function on $(0,1)$ uniformly continuous $?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

$$f:(0,1)\rightarrow [0,1]$$  is  a  differentiable  function .  Is  it  uniformly  continuous  then $?$

Now  $f$  being  differentiable   on $(0,1)$  is  continuous , that  is  easy. Now  I  could  say  it  is  uniformly  continuous  if the differentiability  on  $(0,1)$  implied continuity  on $[0,1]$. What  the  range  being  the  closure  of  the  domain contributes  here $?$

Please  give  some  lead  on  how  to  proceed .

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: What about $\sin\frac1x$?

Comment: the derivative should be bounded

Comment: It  is  continuous , differentiable on $(0,1)$  but  not  uniformly  continuous . Right $?$

Comment: The derivative should be bounded, i.e. $|f'( \zeta)| \leq M$ for all $\zeta \in (0,1)$. Then, according to the mean value theorem, $|f(x) - f(x)| = |f(\zeta)| |x-y| \leq M |x-y|$. Which yields uniform continuity. I am not sure if this is the weakest possible assumption.

Comment: @NigelOvermars If you consider $f(x)=\sqrt x $ you get a uniformly continuous function with an unbounded derivative.

Comment: @Farnight So is it possible to find the weakest sufficient assumption for uniform continuity? And sorry for all the typos in my comment. I was trying to fix them but my internet failed on me, so the five minutes already had passed.

Comment: So  bounded  derivative  is  sufficient  not  necessary  for  uniform  continuity , right?

Comment: I'm not certain this is the best you can do, but if your function $f(x)$ can be extended continuously to $[0,1]$, you get uniform continuity for free. It is one place where my example fails and so makes it a counterexample (and this condition includes the case Farnight gave as well).

Comment: @Clayton Yup, the too are equivalent. If $f$ can be extended continuously to $[0,1]$, then its extension is continuous and therefore, uniformly continuous. And on the other hand if you suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, you can consider a sequence that tends to $0$. ($x_n=\frac1n$ will do), and set $y_n = f(x_n)$ which is bounded so it must have a convergent subsequence that we'll use to construct two new ones $y'_n = f(x'_n)$ s.t $x'_n$ is decreasing and tends to $0$ and $y'_n$ tens to $L$. We'll now define $f(0)=L$ and we need to prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Clayton We can use $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq |f(x)-f(x'_n)|+|f(x'_n)-f(0)|$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ s.t $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac\epsilon2$ and choose $N$ large enough s.t $|f(x'_N)-f(0)|<\frac\epsilon2$ AND $x'_N<\delta$. Then for $x<\delta$: $|f(x)-f(x'_N)|<\frac\epsilon2$ and $|f(x'_N)-f(0)|<\frac\epsilon2$

Answer (score 5):

If we consider $$f(x)=\frac{1+\sin(1/x)}{2},$$ we get a differentiable function that is not uniformly continuous.